# JPA Query with Joins and a Custom Obj that is not Table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am doing a join with a native query.  The returned object is a new object that contains all the attributes in the query.  But it throws an error saying it can't bind object[] to CombinedObj.  What do I do?

```
public interface SettingsRepository extends JpaRepository<Setting, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select s.some_value, o.other_value from settings s inner join other_table o on o.id = s.other_table_id where user_id = :user_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<CombinedObj> find(@Param("user_id") int userId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply project your columns and expect that jpa infer this columns to result object.

It's possible to solve this using a Named Native Query. Like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "settings")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "yourResultSetMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = CombinedObj.class,
                        columns = {
                            @ColumnResult(name = "some_value"), @ColumnResult(name = "other_value")
                        }
                )
        }
)
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Settings.getNativeQuery",
        query = "select s.some_value, o.other_value from settings s inner join other_table o on o.id = s.other_table_id where user_id = :user_id",
        resultSetMapping = "yourResultSetMapping"
)
public class Settings{...}
```